# ReactJs, useState undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usestate

nuevamente vuelvo a acudir a ustedes!
Estoy teniendo unas dudas en cuenta el uso y manejo de useState.

En el siguiente ejemplo tengo un componente que lo que hace es tomar un token que viene del back y mediante una funcion lo autoriza y lo deriva al perfil que sea correspondiente segun el estado de ese usuario, mediante una funcion.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Loading from './../common/Loading';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import API from './../../api';
import PerfilAdmin from './PerfilAdmin';
import {accesNot} from './../../services/useSweetAlert';

const Perfiles = ( props ) => {
 
    const routerHistory = useHistory();
    const [jwtverify,setJwt] = useState();
    const [isFetching,setFetching] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const verifytoken  = async (e)=>{
                try {  
                    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('JWT');
                    const result = await API.get(`auth/authuser/${token}`);
                    setFetching(false)
                    setJwt({...jwtverify,result})
                    //setJwt(result);
                    
                    if(result.data.datosUsers.estado === 1){
                        routerHistory.push("/perfil/perfiladmin")
                        console.log("STATE JWTVERIFY",jwtverify)
                        }   
                      else{
                        accesNot();
                        routerHistory.push('/login')
    
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error()
                }
        }
        
        verifytoken();
        

    },[]);
    
   
   
   

    
    
    return (<>
        {isFetching && <Loading />}
        {<PerfilAdmin usuarios={jwtverify} />}
       
    </>
        )
    }
 
export default Perfiles;
```

Como decia, esta pagina  renderiza solo en un spiner de carga, lo unico que hace es verificar que usuario llega y derivarlo segun corresponda.
Lo que me pasa es que quiero setear el estado -->

```
const [jwtverify,setJwt] = useState();
```

/////////////

```
 const token = sessionStorage.getItem('JWT');
 const result = await API.get(`auth/authuser/${token}`);
 setFetching(false)
 setJwt({...jwtverify,result})
 //setJwt(result);
```

La variable **result** llega perfecto un object con todos los datos del usuario, y yo necesito setear sl **setJwt** con esa informacion.
cuando hago esa carga, por la consola sale ----> **undefined**
Ya probe de varias forma y no estaria encontrando el error de porque no se me setea ese estado.
Muchas gracias y un saludo!!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el `console.log()` que te dice que el estado `jwtverify` está `undefined`? ¿Este `console.log("STATE JWTVERIFY",jwtverify)`?

Comment: Si, ese console.log es el que me tira el UNDEFINED. Gracias un abrazo1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay que olvidar que toda esa lógica la estás ejecutando dentro del `useEffect()`, que en este caso solo se está ejecutando la primera vez en la que se renderiza el componente.

Y como es la primera vez que se renderiza el componente, el estado `jwtverify` está `undefined` porque no le estás asginando un valor inicial en el `useState()`. Entonces es lógico que al querer examinar su valor en el `console.log("STATE JWTVERIFY",jwtverify)` este siga siendo `undefined`.

Eso es porque ese `console.log("STATE JWTVERIFY",jwtverify)` te está mostrando el valor del estado antes de ser seteado. Pero eso no necesariamente quiere decir que no te esté seteando el estado correctamente cuando haces el `setJwt({...jwtverify,result})`.

Entonces, yo te recomendaría que verifiques el valor del estado `jwtverify` mediante el `console.log("STATE JWTVERIFY",jwtverify)` en otra parte del componente para ver si el problema es realmente ese.

Por ejemplo, podrías ponerlo entre el `useEffect()` y el `return` así:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Loading from './../common/Loading';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import API from './../../api';
import PerfilAdmin from './PerfilAdmin';
import {accesNot} from './../../services/useSweetAlert';

const Perfiles = ( props ) => {

const routerHistory = useHistory();
const [jwtverify,setJwt] = useState();
const [isFetching,setFetching] = useState(true);

useEffect(()=>{
    const verifytoken  = async (e)=>{
            try {  
                const token = sessionStorage.getItem('JWT');
                const result = await API.get(`auth/authuser/${token}`);
                setFetching(false)
                setJwt({...jwtverify,result})
                //setJwt(result);
                
                if(result.data.datosUsers.estado === 1){
                    routerHistory.push("/perfil/perfiladmin")
                    /*console.log("STATE JWTVERIFY",jwtverify)*/
                    }   
                  else{
                    accesNot();
                    routerHistory.push('/login')

                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error()
            }
    }
    
    verifytoken();
    

},[]);
   
console.log("STATE JWTVERIFY",jwtverify)//<-- aquí debería mostrar el valor ya actualizado

return (<>
    {isFetching && <Loading />}
    {<PerfilAdmin usuarios={jwtverify} />}
   
</>
    )
}

export default Perfiles;
```

Harías eso solo para verificar si realmente se está seteando o no el estado correctamente.

Ya que hacer esa verificación dentro del `useEffect()`, como expliqué anteriormente, no tendría mucho sentido.

Comment: El hook `useEffect` no se ejecuta junto al componente, el mismo se ejecuta después de que el componente se haya renderizado, el hook `useEffect` le dice a React que su componente necesita hacer algo después del render, react recordará la función que pasó (nos referiremos a ella como nuestro "efecto"), y la llamará más tarde después de realizar las actualizaciones DOM.

Comment: Está bien, no es una mala aclaración. Pero la clave de este caso es saber que si consultas el valor de un estado mediante un `console.log()` dentro de un `useEffect()` como este, te va a mostrar el valor inicial del estado y no su valor actualizado. Y eso pasa independientemente del momento exacto en el que se ejecute este `useEffect()`.

Comment: Buenas colegas, efectivamente, el `console.log()` tenia que ir fuera del `useEffect()` para ver los valores que tenia el STATE. y pude pasarlo mediante props, gracias por la ayuda soy principiante y estos errores basicos se me pasan! saludos!!